# Start ngrok with no output and log ngrok info into a file

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, ngrok

I need some help with starting ngrok with no output and log the ngrok info into a file. it has to start in the same cmd window, but with no output so it can continue executing command.

I've already tried:
`ngrok.exe tcp 22 -log=stdout > ngrok.log`

And:
`start ngrok.exe tcp 22 -log=stdout > ngrok.log`

In the first option it gives a "blank line" and I can't type afterwards. In the second one it starts another window with output and I can type into previous window, but it doesn't store the info into the file, I don't know why.

---

[image: The first option] (The ngrok.log has been overwrited)

[image: The second option] (The ngrok.log is empty)

---

EDIT:

I've got it, I used silentCMD, you can delete this question

Comment: Why not try: `2>&1 ....your_command... >ngrok.log` ?

Comment: Thanks my saviour